# Get path of a file from a subdirectory of a directory in CLASSPATH

Tags: java, file, resources

Given the following directory structure:

```
working-directory
   subfolder1
      file1.wav
      file2.wav
      file3.wav
   subfolder2
      file4.wav
      file5.wav
      file6.wav
   subfolder3
      file7.wav
      file8.wav
      file9.wav
   jar-that-im-running.jar
```

I need to get the path to each wav file. I figured that since the folder is in the working directory, and is thus part of the classpath (if my assumption is wrong, I'd just add the working directory to the classpath), I could just run:

```
String path = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("file1.wav");
```

or

```
String path = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("/file1.wav");
```

but it wouldn't work, unless I specified the folder the wave file was in. This would be fine, but I wouldn't know what folder each wave file is in; I only know their names. I'm going to process all the files one way or another, but the order that I do depends on a config file. Also, I am not going to edit these files directly. Instead, I'm going to be passing them off as arguments to a ProcessBuilder. Since some of the directories in the path may have spaces, which get converted to `%20` in URLs, I figured I could convert them with `path.replaceAll("%20", " ")`. Will I be better off using files, or is there a way to get a specific wav file, without knowing its parent folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try getting from the class loader as a system resource? Here's a snippet of code to illustrate:

```
String path = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("subfolder1/file1.wav");
```

Comment: yeah, that works, but I don't know what folder `file1.wav` is in. sorry, let me clarify my question.

Comment: you can list out the dir and do a look up.